# Go Kazaam transformation returns unexpected result

Tags: json, go

I'm using the kazaam module to define json transformations.
https://github.com/qntfy/kazaam

These are my rules:

```
"rules": [
        {
            "operation": "shift",
            "spec": {
                "Shift": "instruction.context.example1"
            }
        },
        {
            "operation": "concat",
            "spec": {
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "path": "instruction.context.example1"
                    },
                    {
                        "path": "instruction.context.example2"
                    }
                ],
                "targetPath": "Concat",
                "delim": "_"
            }
        },
        {
            "operation": "coalesce",
            "spec": {
                "Coalesce": [
                    "instruction.context.example3[0].id"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Applied to this json:

```
{
    "instruction": {
        "context": {
            "example1": "example1 value",
            "example2": "example2 value",
            "example3": [
                {
                    "id": "example3_1_value"
                },
                {
                    "id": "example3_2_value"
                },
                {
                    "id": "example3_3_value"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this:

```
{
    "Shift": "example1 value",
    "Concat": "null_null"
}
```

So the first operation works, the second returns null_null and the third just doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are applied one after another. What you first rule yields is fed as an input to your second rule and so on, they are chained. So, you first transformation yields an object:

```
{
  "Shift": "example1 value"
}
```

and when the above is given as an input to your second operation - you get the `null` values, since the fields you're referring to - do no exist.
You could try to change the first rule to:

```
        {
            "operation": "shift",
            "spec": {
                "Shift": "instruction.context.example1",
                "instruction.context.example1": "instruction.context.example1",
                "instruction.context.example2": "instruction.context.example2"
            }
        },
```

and see the effect of it.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that shift deletes everything. It all makes sense now.